# Spring Webflux validate multiple slashes in URL

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux

#### The problem:

Hi everyone! I'm migrating an API that validates if an URL has an "empty" path parameters and then throws a specific error.

I've noticed that somewhere in Spring Webflux, some component, is removing these slashes and replacing them with a single slash (e.g.: `/api/books///author` -> `/api/books/author`)

How can I stop this behaviour and keep the pre-processed URL?

Which component is responsible for this behaviour?

#### What I've tried:

1. Created a route like this:

```
// Router Class
fun mainRouter(bookHandler: BookHandler) = router {
  PUT("/api/books/{fields:.*}", bookHandler::putBook)
}

// Handler Class
fun putImage(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
  val fields = req.pathVariable("fields") // Is missing the multiple slashes
}
```

2. Moved this logic to a `WebFilter`:

```
@Component
class Filter : WebFilter {
  override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    // None of these contains the multiple slashes
    val path = exchange.request.path
    val uri = exchange.request.uri
  }
}
```